# Typescript Typings: array of T to map

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Let's say we have a type `T`:

```js
type T = {
  type: string,
}
```

and a function that accepts an array of `T` and returns an object whose keys are the values of every `T.type` and whose values are T

```js
const toMap = (...args: T[]) => args.reduce((res, t) => ({
  ...res,
  [t.type]: t
}), {});
```

so, for this given example:

```js
const a = { type: 'hello' };
const b = { type: 'world' };
const c = { type: 'foo' };

const map = toMap(a, b, c);
```

I expect this result

```js
{
  hello: { type: 'hello' },
  world: { type: 'world' },
  foo: { type: 'foo' },
}

map.hello // correct, { type: 'hello' };

// If I access an unknown property, then the compiler should: 
map.bar // `property bar doesn't exist on type { hello: { ... }, world: {...}, foo: {...} }`
```

how can I write typings for this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by making `T` really generic:

```
function toMap<T extends { type: string }>(...args: T[]): { [type: string]: T } {
  return args.reduce((res, t) => ({
    ...res,
   [t.type]: t
  }), {});
}
```

To be then able to really narrow down the types, you have to type generic types for variable arguments, e.g. `toMap<A>(arg1: A)`, `toMap<A, B>(arg1: A, arg2: B)`.

There are two downsides though:

1) You have to create these overloads for any number of arguments, 
   however that is common in Typescript (see `Object.assign` declaration).

2) Typescript types `{ type: "test" }` as `{ type: string }` by default (which is wanted in 99% of the cases), however therefore we can't infer the keys type to `"test"` directly. To solve this, we have to typecast the string literal to a narrowed down string type `{ type: "test" as "test" }`.

```
// generic overload for one argument
function toMap<A>(arg: A): { [K1 in O<A>]: A };

// generic overload for two arguments:
function toMap<A, B>(arg: A, arg2: B): { [K in O<A>]: A } & { [K in O<B>]: B };

// generic overload for three arguments:
function toMap<A, B, C>(arg: A, arg2: B, arg3: C): { [K in O<A>]: A } & { [K in O<B>]: B } & { [K in O<C>]: C };

// ... repeat for more arguments

// implementation for all kind of args
function toMap<T extends { type: string }>(...args: T[]): { [type: string]: T } {
   return args.reduce((res, t) => ({
     ...res,
    [t.type]: t
  }), {});
}

// Infers the type of "type", which has to be a string, from a given object
type O<V> = V extends { type: infer K } ? K extends string ? K : never : never;

// Narrow down a.type to be "test" instead of string
const a = { type: "test" as "test" }
const b = { type: "test2" as "test2", v: 1 };

const test = toMap(a);
const test2 = toMap(a, b);

console.log(
 test2.test2.v, // works!
 test2.whatever, // doesnt!
 test2.test2.k // doesnt!
);
```

[Try it!](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20toMap%3CA%2C%20K%20extends%20O%3CA%3E%3E(arg%3A%20A)%3A%20%7B%20%5BK1%20in%20K%5D%3A%20A%20%7D%3B%0Afunction%20toMap%3CA%2C%20B%3E(arg%3A%20A%2C%20arg2%3A%20B)%3A%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20O%3CA%3E%5D%3A%20A%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20O%3CB%3E%5D%3A%20B%20%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20toMap%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20string%20%7D%3E(...args%3A%20T%5B%5D)%3A%20%7B%20%5Btype%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20args.reduce((res%2C%20t)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...res%2C%0A%20%20%20%5Bt.type%5D%3A%20t%0A%20%20%7D)%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20O%3CV%3E%20%3D%20V%20extends%20%7B%20type%3A%20infer%20K%20%7D%20%3F%20K%20extends%20string%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%20%3A%20never%3B%0A%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22test%22%20as%20%22test%22%20%7D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22test2%22%20as%20%22test2%22%2C%20v%3A%201%20%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20test%20%3D%20toMap(a)%3B%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20toMap(a%2C%20b)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%0A%20%20test2.test2.v%2C%0A%20%20test2.whatever%2C%0A%20%20test2.test2.whatever%0A)%3B%0A%0A))

Comment: I don't think this really works, keys should be the value of `T.type`

Comment: I think the way to go would be [`keyOf`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: that is great, but on my real case I can't do the type assertion `as <literal>` and it doesn't work. (due to the initial overload, it also errors if you pass more than 1 argument)

Comment: @hitmands to use the ...args: T[] you have to explicitly pass T then

Comment: @htimands if you can't do the type assertion, your code isn't static at compile time, and therefore you can't narrow down the types

Comment: What your doing here is great, really close to the actual solution. And yes, probably we should explicit every argument instead of using rest, but I can't believe that there is no other way for it...

Comment: @Hitmands what do you mean by "other way"? That's the way some internals (like `Object.assign`) are also created, that's actually the best you'll get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189765/discussion-between-hitmands-and-jonas-wilms).

Comment: here is the package I am working on https://github.com/Code-Y/redux-fluent

Comment: can you also help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126385/typescript-definitions-nested-functions/55128561#55128561 ?